# Как сделать чтобы уведомление приходило когда приложение выключено?

Tags: android, unity3d, firebase, firebase-database

Нужно, чтобы приложение отправляло уведомление о изменение в базе данных firebase database

Comment: Так уведомление должно отправляться или приходить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отправлять уведомление вам нужно приложение. Пусть оно будет не основное, но хотя бы маленькое которое будет висеть фоном и наблюдать за событиями в мире и сможет формировать уведомления.